# How can I use tensorflow serving for multiple models

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

How can I use multiple `tensorflow` models? 
I use docker container.

```
model_config_list: {

  config: {
    name: "model1",
    base_path: "/tmp/model",
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  },
  config: {
     name: "model2",
     base_path: "/tmp/model2",
     model_platform: "tensorflow"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Built a docker image from official `tensorflow serving` [docker file](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel-gpu)

Then inside docker image.

```
/usr/local/bin/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_config_file=/serving/models.conf
```

here `/serving/models.conf` is a similar file as yours.

Comment: I think the model_name is not needed in the command line, since it's specified in the config file for each model?

Comment: Yes, you are right. (If `model_config_file` is used, --model_name, --model_base_path are ignored.). Edited now