# Serving multiple tensorflow models using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, tensorflow-serving

Having seen [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1077) github issue and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749024/how-can-i-use-tensorflow-serving-for-multiple-models) stackoverflow post I had hoped this would simply work.

It seems as though passing in the environment variable `MODEL_CONFIG_FILE` has no affect. I am running this through `docker-compose` but I get the same issue using `docker-run`.

---

The error:

```
I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:82] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: model model_base_path: /models/model
I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:461] Adding/updating models.
I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:558]  (Re-)adding model: model
E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:369] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error: Could not find base path /models/model for servable model
```

---

The Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:nightly

COPY ./models/first/ /models/first
COPY ./models/second/ /models/second

COPY ./config.conf /config/config.conf

ENV MODEL_CONFIG_FILE=/config/config.conf
```

---

The compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  serving:
    build: .
    image: testing-models
    container_name: tf
```

---

The config file

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name:  "first",
    base_path:  "/models/first",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        all: {}
    }
  },
  config: {
    name:  "second",
    base_path:  "/models/second",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        all: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After 5th of October you dont have to use nightly anymore, since the lates tensorflow-serving now support config files, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52643620/10455493)

Comment: @krisR89 that's all well and good but it doesn't work either way.

Comment: In tensorflow servings, the default MODEL_NAME  is "model" while MODEL_BASE_PATH is "/models". For some reason your model does not run the config file, and only runs the default "/models/model". I guess you have one of two problems. old servings image or the image is activated incorrectly.
I would try to "docker pull tensorflow/serving" to get the laset version.
And can you add how you run the docker image fil (the command), in case that is the problem?

Comment: @KrisR89 during testing I was explicitly using `:1.11.0-rc0` as the image, as stated in the question you linked that is the revision with these changes. I ran a `docker image prune -a` to ensure I always had the latest image. The command I used was `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`. The problem is stated above. The only thing I can think is that the environment variable is somehow not being honoured by the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no docker environment variable named “MODEL_CONFIG_FILE” (that’s a tensorflow/serving variable, see docker image [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/docker.md#running-a-serving-image)), so the docker image will only use the default docker environment variables ("MODEL_NAME=model" and "MODEL_BASE_PATH=/models"), and run the model “/models/model” at startup of the docker image.
"config.conf" should be used as input at "tensorflow/serving" startup.
Try to run something like this instead:

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 8501:8501 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/models/first/,target=/models/first \
  --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/models/second/,target=/models/second \
  --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/config/config.conf,target=/config/config.conf\
  -t tensorflow/serving --model_config_file=/config/config.conf
```

Comment: While I appreciate the answer I specifically need this to run through `docker-compose` with the dockerfile which packages all of the information into a single image. I'll make a feature request on github issues to see if this can be implemented. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know any workaround for that! An environment variable called MODEL_CONFIG_FILE would probably be a good idea for the docker image, as me, and probably more have been confused about that. Luckily for me, a docker-compose solution was not required in my case. Good luck!

Comment: I've got a work around in place it just isn't as nice and managable as a single image as I had originally hoped. I've added a feature request for the environment variable so hopefully that happens at some point.

Comment: Looks like the reason my earlier attempts to use `docker run` failed was due to [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24029). Having resolved that I'm just adding a `command:` property to my `docker-compose`. Going to give you the green tick as you got me there. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I ran into [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24029) double slash issue for git bash on windows.

As such I am passing the argument, mentioned by @KrisR89, in via `command` in the `docker-compose`.

The new `docker-compose` looks like this and works with the supplied `dockerfile`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  serving:
    build: .
    image: testing-models
    container_name: tf
    command: --model_config_file=/config/config.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is cause serving couldn't find your model.

```
E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:369] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error: Could not find base path /models/model for servable model
```

Your docker compose file didn't mount your model files in the container. So the Serving couldn't find your models.
I suggest to set three configure files.

**1 docker-compose.yml**

**2 .env**

**3 models.config**

`docker-compose.yml`:

Mount your model files from host to the container. I think you could do this :

```
 version: "3"
  services:
        sv:
                image: tensorflow/serving:latest
                restart: unless-stopped
                ports:
                        - 8500:8500
                        - 8501:8501
                volumes:
                        - ${MODEL1_PATH}:/models/${MODEL1_NAME}
                        - ${MODEL2_PATH}:/models/${MODEL2_NAME}
                        - /home/deploy/dcp-file/tf_serving/models.config:/models/models.config
                command: --model_config_file=/models/models.config
```

`.env`:  `docker-compose.yml` loads info from this file.

```
MODEL1_PATH=/home/notebooks/water_model
MODEL1_NAME=water_model
MODEL2_PATH=/home/notebooks/ice_model
MODEL2_NAME=ice_model
```

`models.config`:

```
model_config_list: {
  config {
    name:  "water_model",
    base_path:  "/models/water_model",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        versions: 1588723537
        versions: 1588734567
    }
  },
  config {
    name:  "ice_model",
    base_path:  "/models/ice_model",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        versions: 1588799999
        versions: 1588788888
    }
  }
}
```

And you can see this [serving official document](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/serving_config.md)

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter the same issue/error

The problem coming from the fact that when you run your tensorflow serving using Dockerfile only
and using this command :

###### Dockerfile

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "docker run -it -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 -- entrypoint /bin/bash tensorflow/serving \
&& tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=${MODEL_CONFIG_FILE}}"]
```

your config file wont be applied, only the first part of the command that will applied, since you apply the second one in a bash.

So what I did is that I took he second half of the command and excute it in docker-compose file.

###### Dockerfile :

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "docker run -it -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 -- entrypoint /bin/bash tensorflow/serving ]
```

###### Docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
tensorflow-serving:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile_
container_name: TF_serving_container
ports:
  - "8601:8501"
command: tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file="/models/model/models.config.b"
networks:
  - ml_network
```

Change this /models/model/models.config.b with your config file
Do not forget to network your containers too.