# Use case: Serving multiple models in tf serving: What changes do I need to do in the client.py file for each model hosted?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-serving

I am new to this field.
My usecase is: Serving multiple models in tf serving.I am using docker

I can understand the changes I need to do in the config file(like below):

```
model_config_list: {

  config: {
    name: "model1",
    base_path: "/tmp/model",
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  },
  config: {
     name: "model2",
     base_path: "/tmp/model2",
     model_platform: "tensorflow"
  }
}
```

However, I have 2 challenges:

Challenge 1:

What changes are needed in the client.py file to interact with multiple models?
I referred mnist_client.py:

```
def do_inference(hostport, work_dir, concurrency, num_tests):

  test_data_set = mnist_input_data.read_data_sets(work_dir).test
  channel = grpc.insecure_channel(hostport)
  stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
  result_counter = _ResultCounter(num_tests, concurrency)
  for _ in range(num_tests):
    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = 'mnist'
    request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_images'
    image, label = test_data_set.next_batch(1)
    request.inputs['images'].CopyFrom(
        tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image[0], shape=[1, image[0].size]))
    result_counter.throttle()
    result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds
    result_future.add_done_callback(
        _create_rpc_callback(label[0], result_counter))
  return result_counter.get_error_rate()
```

The above code is for a single model only.

What specific field/variable do I need to add in the code which will identify each of my multiple models uniquely and that unique value I can use while I send request to my model hosted by tensorflow serving inside docker container?

Challenge 2:

For a single model I used this format of client request:

```
python mnist_client.py --server=172.17.0.2:9000 --image=<image folder>
```

What should be the exact format where I am hosting multiple models and every time request is coming for different models. So what should be the correct format of client request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS: I referred the following discussion thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749024/how-can-i-use-tensorflow-serving-for-multiple-models

However I am new to stack overflow thus do not have sufficient reputation points to add comments to the same thread; thus posting a new request for my query.
And tagging @Ultraviolet to guide me if possible with my specific query.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead

Answer (score 0):

Set 'request.model_spec.name' to the name you mentioned in config file, such as "model1".

Change 'request.model_spec.signature_name' to the signature of your model.

In the line "request.inputs['images']", change 'images' to the input tensor name in your model, and change args in make_tensor_proto to your own input . If you have multiple inputs, add the line repeatedly.